# Angular ng-if change span text

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have this JSON file that I am taking objects as products from. When displaying the sizes of the products I want to change a span from "sizes:" to "kids:" when the json object has "kids": "1".

```
<div class="sizes-wrap">
        <span class="size-label"><span>sizes:</span>
        <span class="sizes">{{ item.sizes }}</span>
</div>
```

this code prints Sizes: and the sizes from the json e.g. "128 cm,140 cm,152 cm,164 cm"

I want when in the json object "kids" has a value of 1 to change the word "sizes" to "kids" in the html.

```
<div class="sizes-wrap">
        <span class="size-label"><span>kids:</span>
        <span class="sizes">{{ item.sizes }}</span>
</div>
```

Here is an one of the json objects:

```
  "kids": "0",
  "name": "Product name",
  "sizes": "Small,Medium,Large,X-Large,XX-Large,3XL",
  "kid_adult": "0",
  "free_porto": "0",
  "price": "649,00",
  "package": "0",
  "delivery": "1-2 dage",
  "price_old": "0,00",
  "id": "133714",
  "women": "0"
```

This is what I wanted to achieve after all:

```
<div class="sizes-wrap">
        <span ng-if="item.kids == 0 && item.kid_adult == 0 && item.women == 0" class="size-label"><span>sizes:</span></span>
        <span ng-if="item.kids == 1" class="size-label"><span>kids:</span></span>
        <span ng-if="item.kid_adult == 1" class="size-label"><span>adult kids:</span></span>
        <span ng-if="item.kid_adult == 1" class="size-label"><span>women:</span></span>
        <span class="sizes">{{ item.sizes }}</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Really don't understand what you want exactly..

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Is it  correct, that your spans are not closed?

Comment: thanks I did not see that!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<div class="sizes-wrap">
    <span class="size-label">
        <span ng-if="item.kids == 0">sizes:</span>
        <span ng-if="item.kids == 1">kids:</span> 
    </span>
    <span class="sizes">{{ item.sizes }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This should work, just don't forget the 'size-label' class.  Also not sure why you embedded spans.  just use <span class="size-label" ng-if="item.kids == 0">sizes:</span><span class="size-label" ng-if="item.kids == 1">kids:</span>  That will make sure his class is at the right level.

Comment: Thank you this worked. But i have another question then if i have "kid_adult": "1"; how this would work? Overal the products have 3 categories kids, kids_adult and women. It would be nice to add them too

Comment: @lostintranslation - there was an inner span in the question so I left it in there. This may have been there by mistake but I can't be sure.

Comment: @user1780729 your kid_adult question is not clear.  If you need different output modify the original question with an edit, or ask another question.

Comment: @user1780729 - not sure why you un-marked this as the answer !?

Comment: missclick or something

Comment: Is not recommended use multiple ng-if to show a simple value that could be shown using a ternary operator.

Answer (score 17):

With a javascript expression, in this case using a ternay operator.

```
<span>
    {{ user.biography ? user.biography : 'Without information' }}
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <span ng-if="data.kids === 1">kids:</span>
 <span ng-if="data.kids !== 1">sizes:</span>
```

Maybe, like this, but better to send word with json and insert it, like this:

```
<span class="size_word">{{data.size_word}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using multiple *ngIf you could use an `*ngIf; else`.
Example from [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description) v11:

```
<div *ngIf="condition; else elseBlock">Content to render when condition is true.</div>
<ng-template #elseBlock>Content to render when condition is false.</ng-template>
```