# Why doesn't .change() work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, meteor, event-handling

I have the html

```
<span class="offersReceivedCount">3</span>
```

and I want to run code when the 3 value changes to something else. I'm using handlebars so the real html looks like

```
<span class="offersReceivedCount">{{offers}}</span> Offers Received</p>
```

I tried

```
$(".offersReceivedCount").change(function(){
console.log("change");
});
```

But this never logs anything when the value of `{{offers}}` changes

Do I need a different event type or maybe try different approach?

Comment: because spans do not have change events, only inputs do.

Comment: would h1-3 work or p?

Comment: @chackerian no it would not

Comment: you need to do your change action at the same time you render your template. aside from that, the span never changes, it's replaced in full each time it's "updated"

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something more like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171413/angular-ng-if-change-span-text

Comment: So you are using handlebars, are you using another framework with it?

Comment: I'm using Meteor JS, they have their own way of doing event handling.

Comment: I do not use meteor so I am no help, but I know frameworks I use have the ability to watch a path for a variable change and fire a message.

Comment: I might be confused about this but is there a specific tag I should be using that will let the change event work?

Comment: As for why look at what you're monitoring - it is not changing (the `<span>` element and its attributes).  The `.text()` is, but not the element itself.

Comment: The change event applies to form elements (inputs, etc.) and is triggered when *the user* changes the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `ReactiveVar` and define an [equality function](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar) on that.

```
Template['your-template'].onCreated = function() {
   this['offerReact'] = new ReactiveVar(this['offers'], function(oldValue, newValue) {
       if (oldValue !== newValue) {
           // run the function you want to trigger when value change 
           return false;
       } else {
           // no change, do nothing, just return true;
           return true;
       }

   });
}
```

So, whenever you set the new value to the `offerReact`, the equal function will be triggered and then start to run the event you want to run

Answer (score 1):

A different approach (I don't know how well it would work for you) would be to make an input "look" like a span tag, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f1a990f1/

Then your code will work sense the change function does not work with the span tag.

HTML

```
<input class="offersReceivedCount" type="text" value="333">
<script>
  $(".offersReceivedCount").change(function() {
    alert("change");
  });

</script>
```

CSS

```
input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Still will not fire because the JS changes the value and the change event still will not fire.

Comment: it still won't fire because the whole dang input is replaced each update via the template...

Comment: @epascarello I was attempting a creative approach (honestly did not know if it would work), thanks for the input though.

Comment: this is misleading. `meteor` does not work in the normal way of javascript usually do